# Error upgrade sdk 29 for android 10-Q from android 9-Pie after building app not responding

Tags: android, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I upgrade my android app build on visual studio for mac with sdk 29 to use from android 10 devices.

When I build App, from folder bin/debug/AndroidSoftware.apk my phone with os Android10 crashed every time.

[image: App crashed on android, work on simulator]

**App work on android simulator, not responding on android phone..**

Is there are way to run my app on sdk29 ?

Comment: Can you please share the crash logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

1.Build your apk on yur simulator and it will automatically creates an APK under bin\Debug

2.The file you are looking for is the "Signed apk", e.g. **com.companyname.MyApp-Signed.apk**

3.Install it on your phone.

**Notice**:

"Use Shared Runtime" inside the project properties/Android Options must be Disabled, otherwise Mono Runtime won't be included and your app will crash on phones where Mono isn't installed.